# How to compile .so for Android O without Writable and Executable Segments? How to set specific ELF permissions?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, cmake, elf

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Writable-and-Executable-Segments-Enforced-for-API-level-26

Currently Android O Preview 4 is blocking the loading of certain native libraries due to having Writable and Executable Segments. They determine this by doing a scan of the ELF.

I am trying to compile a native shared object library for Android without such Writable and Executable Segments.

Not being very familiar with this type of low-level compilation-speak, can someone explain how to set the segments to be properly mutually exclusive with respect to writable and executable permissions?

I figure I may need to add some specific flags to my Android.mk file to prevent this issue, with other initial thoughts that this may be something to do with the NDK toolchain being used for compilation.

Any help or advice on where to look is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU toolchains and the Android toolchains have been doing the right thing for a long, long time now.  You can use the `readelf`/`grep` command in the article:

```
$ readelf --program-headers -W libBadFlags.so | grep WE
```

If there is no output, you should be fine.  If there *is* output, you need to track down the source of the writable/executable mapping.  For a `GNU_STACK` header, it is likely an assembler file with a missing annotation (a mere oversight).  But much more obscure things are possible, so there is no generic solution.

But in most cases, no changes to your project should be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Florian, the command you posted will properly show whether the shared object file has writable and executable segments. However I found out that the reason why the NDK was compiling with W+E segments was actually due to my 3rd-party obfuscation tool inserting such segments. Properly configuring obfuscation and post-compilation finalizing tools can also help prevent the .so file from having W+E segments.