# Does Realm respects "Writable and Executable Segments (Enforced for API level >= 26)"

Tags: android, android-ndk, realm, android-8.0-oreo

According to [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#nl) there was a change in NDK that has the following statement

> In apps targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26), native libraries no longer load if they contain any load segment that is both writable and executable.

I am not sure what it means, but I am curious if it was even relevant to the Realm database. It would be nice to get some tips for mentioned change :)

Does this change has any impact on the way Realm initialized? Can we expect any misbehavior due to this change?

Comment: There is a target sdk 26 app for us out there with Realm and it seems to be working and native library loads fine, so I think this isn't a problem

Comment: realm-java won't be impacted by this. I am not quite sure abort realm-js because of https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/src/android/jsc_override.cpp#L90

Comment: I have found related issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512293/how-to-compile-so-for-android-o-without-writable-and-executable-segments-how-t